# How to debug Wordpress on customer site?

Tags: wordpress, debugging, remote-debugging

For in-house Wordpress development, I have had the luxury of using PhpStorm + Xdebug. I am wondering, how do you debug on a customer site when it's unlikely they have a debug extension installed and hesitant about installing additional Wordpress debug plugins? Is good ol' `var_dump` the only answer?

Comment: You could just analyze the code manually.  You can always add new alerts and things into the code where you think there may be trouble.

Comment: Analyzing the code manually with alerts is what I mean by using `var_dump`. I am asking if there are other ways. Maybe PhpStorm has some hidden magic, or perhaps other tools/methods are available?

Comment: I'm suggesting editing the code to add echo statements in places where you would like to see the state of a var.  I work in raw PHP, with no other sorts of plugins. That's how I do my debugging all the time.

Comment: You may want to check on [Wordpress Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin.

Comment: Can you not setup a local development environment and debug there?

Comment: I do have local dev and testing environments, where debugging is not an issue. The scenario I am planning for is if/when customers contact me saying my Wordpress plugin isn't working properly. I often see other developers ask their customers for login credentials when problems arise so they can take a closer look. It leaves me wondering whether there are tools/methods they can use to assist in this sort of remote debugging, or if the norm is to just plant debug statements (`echo`, `var_dump`, etc) in the code.

Comment: I see. I do the same. But as soon as I determine it's not a configuration issue, I just pull the files and db backup and get debugging locally. Makes me nervous doing anything in production. But to answer your question, if you had to do it on their site, I'd fire up a test page with a test template and go to town with `var_dump`, etc.

Comment: That's a good idea about pulling the files/db to debug locally, and +1 for being nervous about doing anything in production. Thanks for the suggestions!